# Using file mask with time constraint in rm command of WinSCP

Tags: winscp

I am trying to connect to remote FTP server to delete the file older than 14 days

The script I am applying is

```
winscp.com /command "open ftp://username:password@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -explicit" "rm -filemask=<14D *.bak " "exit"
```

But I encounter the error :

> Unknown switch 'filemask'.

I wonder what I did wrong here?

Thanks & regards,

Comment: What makes you think that that syntax should work? It's not mentioned [in the docs](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_rm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WinSCP [`rm` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_rm) has no `-filemask` switch.

You can use the [time constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time) directly in the mask argument of the command.

```
rm *.bak<14D
```